# DXL script to find External links on DOORS DB

Tags: ibm-doors

I am using Rational DOORS version 9.6.1.10.
I want to run a DXL script which should recurs all projects and list out all external links with Object ID and module path.

Regards,
Sousan

Comment: Hello Sousan, the usual answer to questions like this is: what did you already try, where exactly are you stuck, which part of the DXL manual is not clear to you? I think the relevant loops you need will be `for <Project> in database`, `for <Item> in <Project>` (or `for <string> in <Project>`, or a loop around all Folders), `for <Object> in entire <Module>` (or a loop which represents the object hierarchy) and `for <ExternalLink> in <Object>`, where <xx> means: "a variable of type xx".